# Winfinite-recursion error when compiling cpp for building android

Tags: android, c++

I am new to this forum and also new in building android-OS.
I am building on Ubuntu 22.04 by using the commands breakfast, lunch, brunch.
During the building process I receive the following error.

```
make: Leaving directory '/home/dakeil/android/lineage/kernel/samsung/universal5433'
[ 38% 29608/76922] //device/samsung/gts2-common/shims/libsensor:libshim_gpsd clang++ libsensor.cpp
device/samsung/gts2-common/shims/libsensor/libsensor.cpp:28:1: warning: all paths through this function will call itself [-Winfinite-recursion]
{
^
```

This is the code:

```
#define LOG_TAG "libshim_gpsd"
#define LOG_NDEBUG 0

#include <cutils/log.h>

#include "libsensor.h"

namespace android
{

ssize_t SensorEventQueue::read(ASensorEvent* events, unsigned long numEvents)
{
        return this->read(events, static_cast<size_t>(numEvents));
}

}
```

I understand that the funtion always calls itself, so I've tried to return nothing by voiding the function but this leads me to other problems.
Can you help me?
btw. The cpp and the corresponding header are coming out from Github, so I can paste the link if needed.

Comment: You need a condition where the function does ***not*** call itself recursively.

Comment: By the way, are there multiple overloads of the `read` function? Perhaps one that takes a `size_t` argument? Then you need to know that it's likely that `size_t` is an alias for `unsigned long`, so you should be getting more errors if that's the case. Please **[edit]** your question to show us a [mre].

Comment: Thanks for answering that fast. Can you help me out with the syntax for the condition?

Comment: Not with the information available. What is the function supposed to actually do? Why do you even have it call `this->read(...)` in the first place? What is the problem that's supposed to solve? Why do you need the `static_cast<size_t>(numEvent)` conversion?

Comment: I am not sure but I expect that there are multiple overloads.

Comment: Not without a [mre] and some idea of what the code is supposed to do. It makes no sense to just recursively call the same function with the same arguments

Comment: Or isn't this your code? Then you really need to contact the author or maintainer of the code. It's likely that they haven't thought about a case where `size_t` and `unsigned long` might be the same. IMO the `unsigned long` overload should just be removed from the code completely, assuming that there's also a `size_t` overload. Perhaps the Github repository allows you to post bugs and issues, then use that.

Comment: You are right, as I stated above from Github, but not recently updated. It is part of [link](https://github.com/universal5433/android_device_samsung_gts2-common/tree/lineage-18.1/shims/libsensor)

Comment: I hoped that it is possible to at least get the function to do nothing, as I do not know if this function is really needed.

Comment: You need to look through the code more, especially the `SensorEventQueue` class. Are there any overloads of the `read` function? What arguments do they take? If there's one that take a `size_t` argument for `numEvents`, then just comment out the declaration and implementation of the overload that takes an `unsigned long` argument.

Comment: If there's *no* overloads of `read` at all, only this single one, then  the code can't be rescued by any other than the authors or maintainers.

Comment: This is the only member function of this class, and there are no references to this class in the repo, so it's not a bad guess that it's never used.

Comment: Thank you @molbdnilo for checking this out. I was able to move further in the building process by simply removing the function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you for the input and ideas. The solution was to remove the function from the building process after checking that there was no reference for that in the repo.